# How to configure remote kernel on a second windows laptop?

Tags: remote-access

Lets say I have two windows laptop both with Mathematica installed on them:

If I want to connect to another mathematica installation on the same machine using the front end I can go to <kbd>Evaluation</kbd> -> <kbd>Kernel Configuration Options...</kbd> -> <kbd>Add</kbd> -> <kbd>Basic Options</kbd> -> <kbd>Local Machine</kbd> -> <kbd>Advanced Options</kbd>.

Then <kbd>Arguments to MLOpen</kbd> is populated as:

```
-LinkMode Launch -LinkName "WolframKernel -wstp -noicon"
```

So I just change the `WolframKernel` with the full path to `WolframKernel.exe` on the local machine and this works. Now I can start the kernel by going to <kbd>Evaluation</kbd> -> <kbd>Start Kernel</kbd>.

But now I want to connect to a mathematica installation on another laptop on the same network so I try the following:

<kbd>Evaluation</kbd> -> <kbd>Kernel Configuration Options...</kbd> -> <kbd>Add</kbd> -> <kbd>Basic Options</kbd> -> <kbd>Remote Machine</kbd> -> <kbd>Advanced Options</kbd> and now <kbd>Arguments to MLOpen</kbd> is populated as:

```
-LinkMode Listen -LinkProtocol TCPIP -LinkOptions MLDontInteract
```

I am assuming I shouldn't change anything here.

Then the other setting <kbd>Shell command to launch kernel</kbd> is populated as:

```
"`java`" -jar "`wolframssh`" username@ wolfram -wstp -LinkMode Connect -LinkProtocol TCPIP -LinkName "`linkname`" -LinkHost `ipaddress`
```

I am assuming I should put in place of `ipaddress`, `IPv4 Address` acquired by running ipconfig on the other laptop (`xxx.xxx.x.x`) and the `linkname` should be the path to the `WolframKernel.exe` in the same format as defined for local. Do I have to define the path like a shared path with computer name here `\\ComputerName\C\Program Files\Wolfram Research\...`?

Also what should I put in place of `java` and `wolframssh`?